# Using Javascript if else to trigger css transition when Navbar is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hamburger menu button that transforms into a 'X' when clicked using css and javascript. Because my Navbar closes when a selection is made, not just when the menu button is clicked, the menu button stays as a 'X'.

I assume that I will need to use an 'if else' statement to tell the menu button to change instead of on click but I am not sure how to code this.

I have included the css code for the style of the button as well as the javascript that is currently used to make it transform and the javascript for the navbar.

The button code is from this site:
http://callmenick.com/post/animating-css-only-hamburger-menu-icons

And the navbar is from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Button CSS Code:

```
.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  background: white;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -20px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -20px;
}

.c-hamburger {
  background-color: #ff3264;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger.is-active {
  background-color: #cb0032;
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger.is-active span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

Button Javascript:

```
(function() {

  "use strict";

  var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

  for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var toggle = toggles[i];
    toggleHandler(toggle);
  };

  function toggleHandler(toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
    });
  }

})();
```

Navbar Javascript:

```
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
open = true;


}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
open = false;

}
```

If someone can help me find the correct code to do this, or has a better idea, I would really appreciate it. I'm quite new to Javascript if you can't already tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite get what you were up to. Did you mean that you wanted your NavBar to be closed when you click on a button not just only when clicking on the 'X'?

If it was so, in the HTML code, you simply need to add the `onclick="closeNav();"` to every button. Something like this

```
<button onclick = "closeNav();"> My Button </button>
```

---

Ok. Since you want the button to change into 'X' when the NavBar is open, you need to give your button an ID, then I think we could use the following Javascript condition.

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
    <span>
        ::before
        "toggle menu"
        ::after
    </span>
</button><!--I copied from the site you provided-->
```

**Javascript**
*I have edited your `sidenav.js`*

```
function decide(){
  if(open == true){
    closeNav();    
  }else{
    openNav();    
  }
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
  document.getElementById("myButton").classList.add("is-active");
  open = true;
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("myButton").classList.remove("is-active");
  open = false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to make it close, I'm trying to make the menu button (.c-hamburger), change into the 'X' when the NavBar is open.

At the moment, the menu button only changes into an 'X' when it is clicked.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Give it a try and please let me know if it works or not. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, thank you for that. It's still not working with your code. I have uploaded the site in its current state and you can see it here: 

http://jonfilm.com/index-test.html

The button that I'm am trying to animate is the big unformatted one on the left. Make sure you reduce the window width to see the mobile navigation bar

Comment: I have updated my answer. I works this time. The old Javascript code I suggested before didn't work (you mistype the `!=` in the condition, though I think it wasn't the reason), just please delete it.

Comment: Your latest update seems to have made it work except it does not revert the X back to the hamburger icon if the NavBar closes by clicking on a navigation option (eg. About). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Nevermind. I just changed the onClick function of the section buttons to decide() and it's working perfectly! Thank you very much for this

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. I have edited the code as above if you'd like to have a look :)

Comment: That also works perfectly and is much cleaner. Thank you so much. I was tearing my hair out with this one